# "cannot be used as a function error"

Tags: c++, function

I am writing a simple program that uses functions found in different .cpp files. All of my prototypes are contained in a header file. I pass some of the functions into other functions and am not sure if I am doing it correctly. The error I get is *"'functionname' cannot be used as a function"*. The function it says cannot be used is the `growthRate` function and the `estimatedPopulation` function. The data comes in through an input function (which I do think is working).

Thanks!

**header file:**

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

//prototypes
void extern input(int&, float&, float&, int&);
float extern growthRate (float, float);
int extern estimatedPopulation (int, float);
void extern output (int);
void extern myLabel(const char *, const char *);

#endif
```

**growthRate function:**

```
 #include "header.h"

float growthRate (float birthRate, float deathRate, float growthrt)     
{    
    growthrt = ((birthRate) - (deathRate))
    return growthrt;   
}
```

**estimatedPopulation function:**

```
    #include "header.h"

int estimatedPopulation (int currentPopulation, float growthrt)
{
    return ((currentPopulation) + (currentPopulation) * (growthrt / 100);
}
```

**main:**

```
#include "header.h"

int main ()
{
    float birthRate, deathRate, growthRate;
    char response; 
    int currentPopulation, years, estimatedPopulation;

    do //main loop
    {  
        input (currentPopulation, birthRate, deathRate, years);
        growthRate (birthRate, deathRate, growthrt);

        estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, growthrt);
        output (estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, growthrt));
        cout << "\n Would you like another population estimation? (y,n) ";
        cin >> response;
    }          
    while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y');

    myLabel ("5-19", "12/09/2010");   

    system ("Pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` inside a header file is very bad mojo.

Comment: really? why is that? Should I put it in every .cpp file instead?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are using growthRate both as a variable name and a function name. The variable hides the function, and then you are trying to use the variable as if it was the function - that is not valid.

Rename the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "header.h"

int estimatedPopulation (int currentPopulation, float growthRate)
{
    return currentPopulation + currentPopulation * growthRate  / 100;
}
```

Comment: Now just remove the growthRate and estimatedPopulation variables (unused) in main and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is right.  You can't use the growthRate variable you declared in main as a function.

Maybe you should pick different names for your variables so they don't override function names?

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
int estimatedPopulation (int currentPopulation,
                         float growthRate (birthRate, deathRate))
```

Make it:

```
int estimatedPopulation (int currentPopulation, float birthRate, float deathRate)
```

instead and invoke the function with three arguments like

```
estimatePopulation( currentPopulation, birthRate, deathRate );
```

OR declare it with two arguments like:

```
int estimatedPopulation (int currentPopulation, float growthrt ) { ... }
```

and call it as

```
estimatedPopulation( currentPopulation, growthRate (birthRate, deathRate));
```

#### Edit:

Probably more important here - C++ (and C) names have **scope**. You can have two things named the same but not at the same time. In your particular case your `grouthRate` variable in the `main()` **hides** the function with the same name. So within `main()` you can only access `grouthRate` as `float`. On the other hand, outside of the `main()` you can only access that name as a function, since that **automatic** variable is only visible within the scope of `main()`.

Just hope I didn't confuse you further :)

Comment: This is not correct, I think. Look at main where the `estimate...` called.

Comment: Maybe, hard to tell which line is the "correct" intention here. Revised anyway.

Comment: I cant consolidate it into one function because i they both have to return a value: growthrate and estimated population. To do the second option do i need to have the return value of growthrate be growthrt?

Comment: @Matt, just avoid naming functions and variables with the same exact words. Adopt some convention like - function names are in **camelBackNotation**, but variables have **underscore_separated_names**, or whatever makes it clear.

Comment: anyway to post code in these reply comments so I can show you my changes?

Comment: Alright, edited growthrate and estimatedPopulation functions, and main. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Matt, wrong - C and C++ functions **copy** their parameters, so `var` in `int func( int var ) { ... }` is a **local variable** in that function with the value you gave it when you invoked the function. Further, a function *returns* value via `return` statement. You have to assign it like `int a = func( b, c );` or use it in expression like `int a = 12 + func( b, c );`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a function as a parameter. Simply remove it from estimatedPopulation() and replace it with 'float growthRate'. use this in your calculation instead of calling the function:

```
int estimatedPopulation (int currentPopulation, float growthRate)
{
    return (currentPopulation + currentPopulation * growthRate / 100);
}
```

and call it as:

```
int foo = estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, growthRate (birthRate, deathRate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your estimated population function to take a growth argument of type float.  Then you can call the growthRate function with your birthRate and deathRate and use the return value as the input for grown into estimatedPopulation.

```
float growthRate (float birthRate, float deathRate)     
{    
    return ((birthRate) - (deathRate));    
}

int estimatedPopulation (int currentPopulation, float growth)
{
    return ((currentPopulation) + (currentPopulation) * (growth / 100);
}

// main.cpp
int currentPopulation = 100;
int births = 50;
int deaths = 25;
int population = estimatedPopulation(currentPopulation, growthRate(births, deaths));
```